# TI PCM51xx DAC Charge Pump Failure

Tags: dac, charge-pump

I'm using a [PCM5122](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5122.pdf) and previously a PCM5102 (this is the same part, but without the I2C/SPI interface) in my design and I've had a couple of prototypes end up with the 3.3v rail shorted to ground. A little investigation has yielded that the CPVDD (Charge Pump) pin is bringing the rail near ground. Similarly, the VNEG pin has only 20k ohm resistance to ground. No other pins appear to be shorted. The outputs of the DAC connect directly to an onboard amp, as well as being tee'd off into a vehicle amplifier.

My question is this: **What could cause this kind of damage to the DAC and what can I do to prevent it?** I have not done anything outside the box with the implementation, other than change the output filter to supply a higher output load.

Here is my schematic:
[image]

Here's my PCB layout:
[image]

Comment: You have DGND disconnected in the schematics. That can't be right?

Comment: @Justme - It is amazing the things one misses after staring at something too long. DGND was absolutely disconnected! If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it :). I'm surprised this ever worked and that my other prototypes haven't blown up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DGND is disconnected in the schematics, it can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's also worth noting that VCOM/DEMP should have also been tied to GND in software control mode (as I am using the DAC), per the datasheet.

Comment: No it depends on the mode you use (VCOM or VREF mode), and that also affects the PLL settings. So don't tie it directly to GND, at least with a 0R so you can later decide between 0R and capacitor, depending on which mode is better in your case.

Comment: VREF mode is perfectly fine for me (I have tested both). Should I still not tie it to GND?

Comment: Eval kit has 10k pull-up; the datasheet may mean it is internally tied to GND in this mode but it does not clearly say if it should be externally tied or not. I don't remember how it ended up any more, but you can ask in TI support forums.